# Get the right templated class instantiation from an enum value

Tags: c++, c++11

I have got this little problem, please have a look:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class AnimalType
{
   bird,
   mammal,
   lizard,
   fish,
};

template<int LEGCOUNT, typename T>
class AbstractAnimal
{
public:
   T printLegCount() { std::cout << LEGCOUNT << std::endl; return 0; }
};

// The second parameter is NOT the leg type, it is just 
// a parameter to make each method signature unique
// as it is in my real source code
class Mammal : public AbstractAnimal<4, double>{};
class Bird : public AbstractAnimal<2, int>{};
class Lizard : public AbstractAnimal<4, float>{};
class Fish : public AbstractAnimal<0, long long>{};


void printLegCount(AnimalType animalType)
{
   switch (animalType)
   {
      case AnimalType::bird: Bird{}.printLegCount(); break;
      case AnimalType::mammal: Mammal{}.printLegCount(); break;
      case AnimalType::lizard: Lizard{}.printLegCount(); break;
      case AnimalType::fish: Fish{}.printLegCount(); break;
   }
}

int main()
{
   AnimalType type = AnimalType::bird;
   printLegCount(type);
   return 0;
}
```

Actually the AnimalType enum in my code is huge (40 or more entries). The switch in printLegCount is also huge. And I have a few printLegCount-like functions to write with a switch case.

So I end up writting a long and terrible switch case each time I need to instantiate some classes. All I have on input is a runtime enum value (cannot be resolved at compile time). To one enum value corresponds one class. At first I wanted to write a vector or an array but my classes don't share any common ancestor. Actually I don't want a common ancestor because I cannot have any common methods in it, this is why printLegCount returns a T, to mimic my production code. The common ancestor would be an empty shell that I would have to downcast to the real type to use it.

Is there a way to write something like :

```
void printLegCount(AnimalType animalType)
{
   no_idea_how_to_write_it(animalType).printLegCount(); // h4lp plx
}
```

Instead of the huge switch case.

Comment: Why do you have an `enum class` and a `class` for animals? If you used a base class instead this would be trivial.

Comment: The enum class comes from a client api, this is an input, the animal class is my code. My code processes the input from the api.

Comment: If the animal class code is yours, why do you have a templated number of legs? I suspect it should always be `unsigned int` unless the animal had a terrible, terrible accident.

Comment: I laughed, but this doesn't really help. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a dispatcher:

```
// Same order as enum AnimalType
using AnimalTuple = std::tuple<Bird, Mammal, Lizard, Fish>;

// Helper function as gcc has problem to expand variadic for the lambda
template <typename T, typename F>
std::function<void()> call_with_default(F&& f)
{
    return [f]() {f(T{});};
}

template <typename F, std::size_t...Is>
void dispatch(AnimalType animalType, F&& f, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    std::function<void()> fs[] = {
        call_with_default<std::tuple_element_t<Is, AnimalTuple>>(f)...
    };
    fs[static_cast<int>(animalType)]();
}

template <typename F>
void dispatch(AnimalType animalType, F f)
{
    constexpr auto AnimalCount = std::tuple_size<AnimalTuple>::value
    dispatch(animalType, f, std::make_index_sequence<AnimalCount>{});
}
```

And then call it:

```
dispatch(animalType, [](auto t) { t.printLegCount(); });
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/9UYUX1)

If you can't use C++14, you have to create your generic functor instead

```
struct LegCountPrinter {
    template <typename T>
    void operator(T t) const { t.printLegCount(); }
};

// later
dispatch(animalType, LegCountPrinter{});
```

Comment: I have no other word than thanks a lot ! This is really what I wanted. There is only a little downside, this is C++14 but I believe it is not an issue, I may be able to upgrade my compiler.

Comment: @Sandoli: Just added code for C++11 without generic lambda.

Comment: I think you should add some explanation on how the code works (code-only answers are not very useful).

Comment: From what I understand, the idea is to find the right type in the tuple with the help of the enum value as index. That is why the tuple must be ordered like the enum. Now for the technical details...

Comment: I create an array of functions (indexed by the `enum`) where each function is for one specific type (thanks to Pack expansions of variadic template).

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about something like this?

```
#include <iostream>

enum class AnimalType
{
   bird,
   mammal,
   lizard,
   fish,
};

template<AnimalType LEGCOUNT, typename T>
class AbstractAnimal
{
public:
   T printLegCount() { std::cout << (int)LEGCOUNT << std::endl; return 0; }
protected:
};

class Mammal : public AbstractAnimal<AnimalType::mammal, double>{};
class Bird : public AbstractAnimal<AnimalType::bird, int>{};
class Lizard : public AbstractAnimal<AnimalType::lizard, float>{};
class Fish : public AbstractAnimal<AnimalType::fish, long long>{};


template<AnimalType A, class T> void printLegCount() {
  AbstractAnimal<A, T>{}.printLegCount();
}

void foo() {
  printLegCount<AnimalType::bird, int>();
}
```

Comment: No. I would like a method that takes an animal type as parameter, and find the right animal class, instantiates it and makes some process on it WITHOUT writing a long switch case.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'finding'. You are not 'finding' anything here, you are creating an new instance. If the question is about finding a specific object, than you can simply put a unique_ptr<AbstractAnimal> int `std::unordered_map` and perform lookup there. That would be a compile-time lookup, though, significantly slower than switch().

Comment: So you want to create a _factory_?

Comment: The idea is that each class has a method printLegCount but the signature is different. One has a `double printLegCount`, another one as a `int printLegCount`... So I cannot have a common ancestor, and I believe I cannot put my many different Mammal, Bird, Lizard, Fish instances in any container.

Comment: Eh, why is number of legs is double? I am still not sure what are you trying to do. I have to repeat my question. Do you want to create a new instance based on the argument? Do you want to find the alredy existing instance? Or do you simply want to call the function on newly constructed and discared instance? Your code does the later, and this is what I've shown you.

Comment: No, number of legs is not a double. I just added a return type to printLegCount to mimic what I have in my production code. The idea is : each animal has a different printLegCount method signature. If I just wrote "void printLegCount()", someone would tell me : "Hey, why don't you add a common ancestor to your many animal classes?".

Comment: Got this part. What about the actual question? Your usage is still unclear.

Comment: Pleave have a look to Jarod42 answer, it is exactly what I want, a simple short method which takes an animal type as parameter, find and instantiate the corresponding animal class and apply some processing on it.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you :) I'd suggest you accept @Jarod42 answer :)